# RESTlet eclipse update site - out of date?

Tags: java, eclipse, restlet

I'm investigating [RESTlet](http://restlet.com). We use Eclipse for Java development, and using the Eclipse Update site for RESTlet modules seems ideal.

I just noticed that the Eclipse Update Site they point to: http://p2.restlet.com/2.2/ , has `2.2.0` versions only. According to http://restlet.com/ , the latest stable is `2.2.2`.

There is no specific update site for `2.2.2` (or if there is, it's not trivial).

Anyone knows what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for the Maven route, seems to work better.

```
Downloading: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.2.2/org.restlet-2.2.2.pom
Downloaded: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.2.2/org.restlet-2.2.2.pom (614 B at 0.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.parent/2.2.2/org.restlet.parent-2.2.2.pom
Downloaded: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.parent/2.2.2/org.restlet.parent-2.2.2.pom (10 KB at 39.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.2/org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.2.2.pom
Downloaded: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.2/org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.2.2.pom (3 KB at 7.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.restlet.com/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.2.3/jackson-core-2.2.3.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.2.3/jackson-core-2.2.3.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.2.3/jackson-core-2.2.3.pom (6 KB at 39.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.restlet.com/com/fasterxml/oss-parent/10/oss-parent-10.pom
```

That solves my problem, so I'll answer my own question (can do so in 2 days, shszz.. well ok then).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue.
The metadata of the eclipse update site has been refreshed.

Comment: I find using a pom file better anyways, but thanks for the follow-up!